# SharePoint Calendar End Time Column And Workflow Updating

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to update the End Time column using a SharePoint Designer workflow. I simply want to add 15 minutes to any new event created, but I cannot update the End Time column. I constantly receive this error:

> The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more
>   columns for the item require a different type of information.

I am able to add 15 minutes to any generic data column in the calendar, but not the End Time column.

Any ideas on how to update the column?

Comment: Are you saying that you could do it to other SPFieldDateTime columns? can you put your code how you are doing?

Comment: Yes, I can update a Date Time field that I've added to a calendar list. There isn't any code, I've built the workflow using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Does the workflow run on item update? SharePoint will not a workflow to loop e.g. you update the titem, the workflow updates the end time, this update restarts the workflow, so the emd time is updated etc

Have you tried using a calculated column for the end date? This [link](http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-add-and-subtract-hours-and.html) will show you how to add minutes to a time

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :)
I found the solution for this: EndDate should be updated the same time as EventDate.
You can use the Update List item action and update both fields with it to get rid of the error message.